# How do I avoid the usage of the "for" loop in this bash function?

Tags: bash

I am creating this function to make multiple grep's over every line of a file. I run it as following:

```
cat file.txt | agrep string1 string2 ... stringN 

function agrep () {  
   for a in $@;  do
     cmd+=" | grep '$a'";
   done ;
   while read line ; do
     eval "echo "\'"$line"\'" $cmd";
   done;
}
```

The idea is to print every line that contains all the strings: `string1`, `string2`, ..., `stringN`. This already works but I want to avoid the usage of the `for` to construct the expression:

```
| grep string1 | grep string2 ... | stringN
```

And if it's possible, also the usage of `eval`. I tried to make some expansion as follows:

```
echo "| grep $"{1..3}
```

And I get:

```
| grep $1 | grep $2 | grep $3
```

This is almost what I want but the problem is that when I try:

```
echo "| grep $"{1..$#}
```

The expansion doesn't occur because bash cant expand `{1..$#}` due to the `$#`. It just works with numbers. I would like to construct some expansion that works in order to avoid the usage of the `for` in the `agrep` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
agrep () {
    if [ $# = 0 ]; then
        cat
    else
        pattern="$1"
        shift
        grep -e "$pattern" | agrep "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: thanks for the support this was very useful,  but i have one question, the if statement is optional or is necessary, it's unclear for me that if the **if**  is true then execute **cat**, i am not sure about the usage of that.

Comment: In the case of no arguments given at all, or after all of the arguments have been peeled off, `agrep` needs to pass its input through to its output unmodified. The `cat` command does that.

Comment: ok thanks for the support an explanation, this was very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running each multiple `grep`s on each line, just get all the lines that match `string1`, then pipe that to `grep` for `string2`, etc. One way to do this is make `agrep` recursive.

```
agrep () {
    if (( $# == 0 )); then
        cat   # With no arguments, just output everything
    else
        grep "$1" | agrep "${@:2}"
    fi
}
```

It's not the most efficient solution, but it's simple.

(Be sure to note [Rob Mayoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36380985/1126841), which is the POSIX-compliant version of this.)

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

you can avoid multiple grep calls and constructing the command by switching to awk

```
awk -v pat='string1 string2 string3' 'BEGIN{n=split(pat,p)} 
               {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if($0!~p[i]) next}1 ' file
```

enter your space delimited strings as in the example above.

Comment: Depending on the patterns to match, it may be tricky to find a way to pack them all into a single delimited string. (What if one of the strings itself contains whitespace, for example?)

Comment: it doesn't have to be space delimited (mimicking original example) you can pick any unused char as a delimiter but need to split with that too.

Comment: In general, you can't guarantee there *is* an unused character, or at least know ahead of time what is unused. It's the same problem arrays were introduced to solve.

Answer (score 2):

*Not* building a string for the command is definitely better (see [chepner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36380995/2072269) and [Rob Mayoff's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36380985/1126841) answers). However, just as an example, you can avoid the `for` by using `printf`:

```
agrep () { 
    cmd=$(printf ' | grep %q' "$@")
    sh -c "cat $cmd"
}
```

Using `printf` also helps somewhat with special characters in the patterns. From `help printf`:

```
In addition to the standard format specifications described in printf(1),
printf interprets:

  %b    expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
  %q    quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
  %(fmt)T output the date-time string resulting from using FMT as a format
        string for strftime(3)
```

Since the aim of `%q` is providing output suitable for shell input, this should be safe.

Also: You almost always want to use `"$@"` with the quotes, not just plain `$@`.